# Поименованные аргументы из Python в с++ через SWIG

Tags: c++, python, swig

Объявляю в С++ class, ну например:

```
сlass Point
{
public:
    Point(int color, int x=0, int y=0);
};
```

Теперь из Python пробую создать объект

```
p = Point(16, y=0)
```

Но получаю что-то вроде:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'y'
```

Как при помощи SWIG генерировать для Python интерфейс с поименованными аргументами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в Ваш интерфейсный файл, например point.i, следующую строку:

```
%feature ("kwargs") Point;
```